# Trying to get d3 ticks to show up every X months, formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm on d3 v5.

I'm trying to get ticks on the X axis to show up every 5 months and be formatted like this "Jan 17". Here is what I'm doing based off this the info in this page: https://observablehq.com/@d3/scale-ticks :

```
// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%b %y")

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
x.ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(5)).map(formatTime)
```

But this isn't working at all, and I can't figure out why. It doesn't even change the result. This is what I'm seeing:

[image]

Here is something else I've tried that throws an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: svg.append(...).attr(...).call(...).ticks is not a function`

```
// Add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(5))
        .tickFormat(formatTime);
```

So I tried removing the ticks function and just trying tickFormat and that isn't working at all. The tick format isn't changed:

```
 // Add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .tickFormat(formatTime);
```

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <style>
        /* 13. Basic Styling with CSS */

/* Style the lines by removing the fill and applying a stroke */
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ffab00;
    stroke-width: 3;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot {
    fill: #ffab00;
    stroke: #fff;
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

    </style>
</head>
<!-- Body tag is where we will append our SVG and SVG objects-->
<body>
</body>

<!-- Load in the d3 library -->
<script src="lib/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 70},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%b %y")

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
x.ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(5)).map(formatTime)

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("boardgame_ratings.csv").then(function(data) {

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date)
      console.log("date", d.date)
      d.running_total = +d.running_total;
  });
  console.log("d", data)
  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.running_total; })]);

  // Add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(5))
        .tickFormat(formatTime);


  // Add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});

</script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An axis doesn't render immediately, so we have to pass the `ticks` to [`Axis.ticks()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_ticks) for it to work, in other words, **pass the ticks to the axis instead of the domain**.

The same goes for the format, specified using `axis.tickFormat()`.

```
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom()
        .ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(4))
        .tickFormat(formatTime));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <style>
        /* 13. Basic Styling with CSS */

/* Style the lines by removing the fill and applying a stroke */
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ffab00;
    stroke-width: 3;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot {
    fill: #ffab00;
    stroke: #fff;
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

    </style>
</head>
<!-- Body tag is where we will append our SVG and SVG objects-->
<body>
</body>

<!-- Load in the d3 library -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.16.0/dist/d3.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 70},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%b %y")

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);


// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
(function(data) {

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date)
      d.running_total = +d.running_total;
  });
  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.running_total; })]);

  // Add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(d3.utcMonth.every(4))
        .tickFormat(formatTime));


  // Add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

})(
[
    {
        date: "2017-01-01",
        running_total: 2,
    },
    {
        date: "2020-07-01",
        running_total: 2,
    },
]
);

</script>
```

Comment: Thats giving me an error: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: svg.append(...).attr(...).call(...).ticks is not a function"

Comment: Make sure you call it on `d3.axisBottom()`.